# How to lookup remote JNDI

Tags: java, jms, jndi, ibm-mq, mq

Is it possible to lookup remote JNDI in IBM MQ. My scenario is I have an MQ installation on machine A, with JNDI resources(JMS Administered objects in MQ Explorer).Now if I want to connect to MQ via JMS from standalone JAVA class, I can lookup from "file://JNDI_FACTORY". All examples only mention this. But is it possible if I want that standalone JAVA class on machine B. That is machine B has JAVA Class which has to connect to remote JNDI(on machine A) and look up for Connection Factory. Can I use some thing like "hostname of A:port" for property ContextProviderUrl in java class in machine B, to access remote objects from machine A?

Also suggest me on remote JNDI lookup.

Please help!

THANKS CHAKRI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simplicity all MQ JMS samples use a File JNDI to demonstrate usage of initial context. You can modify the samples to look up a LDAP server for connection factory and destination information.

First in MQExplorer you need to choose `LDAP Server` option to save the connection factory and destination information to a LDAP server. Then in your application you need to have code that looks like this:

```
  String initialContextUrl = "ldap://myhost:991/c=uk,o=ACME"
  String contextFactory = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
  Hashtable environment = new Hashtable();
  environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, contextFactory);
  environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, initialContextUrl);
  Context context = new InitialDirContext(environment);
```

Please see the Infocenter topic [*Using JNDI to retrieve administered objects in a JMS application*](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/jm24350_.htm) for details and additional code samples.

Comment: Yes, T.Rob. It was an issue with the entry I had for SO in my etc/hosts file. I removed the entry and I am back.

Comment: One more thing is, I am using MQexplorer to handle queue manager, and when I connect to MQ using JMS with JNDI lookup, using qcf.createQueueConnection(); I am getting "JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager" error, all posts/blog mention of this error, but they say to remove CHAUTH for queuemanager and so on... How do I work this out using MQExplorer, Please help me on this

Comment: Actually disabling CHLAUTH is NOT advised as doing so opens up your queue manager to the world. It's OK if this is a test queue manager. Using runmqsc you can disable channel authentication. In runmqsc issue "ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)" command to disable channel authentication.