# External lookup for Tomcat JNDI

Tags: tomcat, jndi

I want to configure a datasource within Tomcat 9.x and access it from the outside world. From the early days of my development career I can remember, that you have to pass some properties on creation of the InitialContext and then it worked well.

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
        props.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"????????");
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);

        DataSource ds  = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:jdbc/ordering");
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

No glue, whether it is possible under Tomcat ...

Any help appreciated and thx in advance.

Comment: So what's the problem? Any error?

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific ... First I don't know the Provider URL, second I don't know whether it is possible in general.

Comment: Seems [possible](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97688_16/generic.903/a97690/jndi.htm)

Comment: Ok, and how? I failed ... Must have the values for constructing the InitilaContext correctly. See question marks above.

Comment: May be 2 tomcats, one local and one on docker could help to reproduce the scenario.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15274179/2834978) and [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.3/html/development_guide/remote_jndi_lookup)

Comment: https://github.com/h-thurow/TomcatJNDI finally I found a solution ... Thx for your efforts and time